# How to prevent desktop applications from starting in the background in Win 10

Tags: windows-10, process, uninstall, reinstall

There are some desktop applications (not the metro apps) on my Win 10. They can only be started once. If I close these apps and restart them, they will some how start themselves as background processes and keep running in the background without showing up any user interfaces. These processes will keep using some amount CPU power and memory. Even if I kill the background processes and restart them, they just start up in the same fashion as background processes. I have to restart my Windows in order to start these applications again.

At first, I thought these are just bugs in the applications (one of them is the well known VLC player), but then later I see more and more applications behaving like this and I suspect this is a problem caused by Windows instead. These applications usually work fine in the beginning. They only start behaving like this strangly after using them a period of time, like a few months to a few years. I didn't do anything to them, nor did I change any settings for them. I just start the application as usual and out of the blue I discover them becoming like this.

I have tried uninstalling these applications and reinstalled them but there is no difference after reinstalling. I even tried removing any cache/user settings for these applications but no use.

I searched on the web for how to prevent apps from starting as background apps, but the solutions I've found only applies to the Metro style apps, not the traditional desktop apps.

Is it because of virus? Is it because of harddisk failures? Or just some bugs in Windows?

So here I am, asking to see if anyone has similar problems and see they have any solutions for this.

Comment: I'm not sure why they still keep starting even after a uninstall but a virus scan wouldn't hurt in this case.

Comment: Vicus scan has been run and no threat has been detected.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you and I've found the solution myself.

It is not a Windows bug but it is rather a software bug. The problem seems to be caused by my Wacom tablet. There is a known issue with Wacom tablet conflicting with the Qt framework. Since Qt is a very popular framework with a lot of dependent applications, a lot of applications are affected by this problem if they have Wacom tablet installed. Just to list a few of the affected common applications:

- Krita
- Autodesk Maya
- MuseScore
- VLC Player
- Adobe Photoshop Album
- Pencil2D
- PDFedit
- TeamViewer
- Scribus
- Not to mention the KDE list of applications

Comment: A link to the issue might be nice.

Comment: See [link](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-6127)